# Append to an excel file with POI without reading data

Tags: java, memory-management, apache-poi

I've been trying to put a large amount of data to an excel file HSSFWorkbook,
(~9 million rows) and I don't think the JVM memory can handle it.

So I want to write the rows in the excel file in chunks to conserve memory.
My idea is to repeatedly append chunks of rows.

However, while querying the data in the excel file it appears that I have to read the data into memory again, which defeats my purpose.

How do i achieve this?

"Basically, how to append chunks of rows on an existing excel file without reading it?"

Comment: This won't allow you to append to an existing workbook (as far as I can tell) but it will allow you to stream to a new workbook: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html

Comment: If you really wanted to conserve memory, you’d switch to using a CSV instead, and scripts to append text to it. Having said that, xslx is a text(XML based) format too, so you should be able to do this without POI or the limitations it brings. The only question is how is your data receiver designed?

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, post as answer so i can vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POI also provides a streaming API: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html